# CodenameOne - Getting the text size inside TextViews or TextAreas

Tags: java, webview, codenameone, textfield, font-size

My CodenameOne app has a BrowserComponent in the layout (it's a WebView).

It has also other components like TextFields.

I need that the text in the BrowserComponent has the same size as the text in the TextFields (default value).

I set the text size inside the BrowserComponent in HTML, using the CSS font-size property.

I tried with this instruction:

```
int size=textField.getStyle().getFont().getSize();
```

and then the HTML is created, where there is this string inside a suitable tag definition:

```
"style=\"font-size:"+String.valueOf(size)+"px;\"";
```

but the result is 0.

Is it possible to get that number to be correct from any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You should use `getUnselectedStyle()` and not `getStyle()` before getFont().

The `getSize()` method is for system fonts as explained in [the docs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Font.html#getSize--). You got the response of [SIZE_MEDIUM](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.codename1.ui.CN.SIZE_MEDIUM) which isn't what you want.

Try `getHeight()` or `getPixelSize()` after getFont().